# Microsoft Edge browser not correctly filtering PDF files in upload file dialog with Contact Form 7

Tags: forms, cross-browser, files, file-extension, file-upload

I am using a Contact Form 7 which allows you to attach a PDF file to the message:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/contact-form/

Chrome correctly shows a filter:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox correctly shows a filter:

[image: Firefox]

Internet Explorer also shows a filter:

[image: IE]

But Microsoft Edge:

[image: Edge]

It is not setting a filter. Is this:

- A bug with the Contact Form 7 plugin?
- A bug with Microsoft Edge?

I do not have access to other desktop browsers, eg. Safari, to test.

Comment: To test other browsers I recommend a service that lets you use a wide variety of browsers remotely.   I use https://crossbrowsertesting.com/ for $30/month.    Others are https://www.browserstack.com/ and https://www.browserling.com/ and http://www.browsera.com/

Comment: I am not really in a position to pay for such features as this is not a financial enterprise. I was hoping a user had previous experience with Edge for this matter. Or Microsoft personnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Contact Form 7 is using `accept=".pdf"` on the file input HTML. 
 This instructs browsers that know how, to only show files which have a file name matching the pattern.  Ideally your contact form would also specify the PDF mime type which would give slighty wider browser support, especially on mobile:  `accept=".pdf,application/pdf"`.   However, even that won't work with Microsoft Edge.

It is a known issue that Microsoft Edge doesn't really support the accept attribute for file input.   In Microsoft Edge the `All files (*)` drop down contains the filter, but it is never selected by default.  Users have to manually select it from the drop down to get the filter applied.  [Can I Use reports](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept) that Edge does not support this feature even though Microsoft Internet Explorer does.

[image]

On StackOverflow [Limit file format when using `<input type=“file”>?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file) says that this is a browser client side feature that is easy to override or hack.   If it is important that users can only upload PDF files, your server side controller needs to enforce that.